# Thread Cannot Access Object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a UserControl that is added to my Main window.  The Main code continuously receives TCP messages and interacts with the UserControl accordingly.  One of the UserControl's methods that is called by Main is AddMessage:

```
internal void AddMessage(Paragraph p)
{
    if (txtViewer.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        txtViewer.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                txtViewer.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

The line within Dispatcher.Invoke always throws an InvalidOperationException.  I've looked around at similar issues, and most of them were cases where the Dispatcher wasn't being used, so I don't know why my code isn't working.  I suppose I'm using it incorrectly, or it may have something to do with the Paragraph object being passed between threads.

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: Did you try to call `AddMessage` within the UI Thread (= without calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`) in order to see if there is something wrong not related with threads?

Comment: Use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Comment: I am not an expert on this by a long shot.  I had a similar problem in could not bind a DocumentViewer asynch as FlowDocument derived from Dispatcher.  The UI cannot talk to a object the derives from Dispatcher on another thead.  I had to serialize the FlowDocument to string (does not derive from dispatcher) using XamlWriter.Save then de-serialize in a Converter.

Comment: @AS-CII - I was able to call AddMessage in the constructor of the UserControl with no issues.

Comment: @BalamBalam: That worked like a charm. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in could not bind a DocumentViewer asynch as FlowDocument derived from Dispatcher. The UI cannot bind to an object that derives from Dispatcher on another thead. I had to serialize the FlowDocument to string (does not derive from dispatcher) using XamlWriter.Save then de-serialize in a Converter.

Comment: I ended up converting the IsAsynch = true to a BackgroundWorker and got a 10X performance improvement.  There is a lot of overhead in the serializing and de-serializing and you lose the benefits of dispatcher.   And you also gain the ability to cancel.  IsAsynch = true is best for an expensive task that returns a small string.

Answer (score 1):

You check the access on the `Dispatcher` of the `txtViewer` but invoke on some *other* `Dispatcher` if `CheckAccess` fails, you know nothing about said `Dispatcher`. You want to invoke on the `txtViewer.Dispatcher` instead.

Comment: @Jared: What is the exception message? Are there any inner exceptions and if so, what do they say?

Comment: InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
No inner exceptions.

Comment: @Jared: And you are sure that it's on the invoke-line? Usually you should obtain a reference to the relevant Dispatcher on the UI-thread, so even calling `txtViewer.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` on another thread should be quite dangerous as you access the dispatcher via `txtViewer` instead of using a direct reference.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the object being frozen.

> The idea of an object deriving from Freezable is that it normally is
>   in a read/write state, but can be explicitly put into a read-only
>   state using the Freeze method.  A frozen object can be used more
>   efficiently in WPF because it doesn’t need to notify consumers of the
>   object that its value has changed.
>
> Graphical objects in WPF like brushes and 3D geometries derive from
>   Freezable.  Initially unfrozen, a change to one of these objects
>   results in consumers of the objects being notified of the change.
>
> If you have an object deriving from Freezable that you don’t plan to
>   change, you can make the object read-only using the Freeze method.
>
> After freezing the object, if you try
>   modifying it, you’ll get an InvalidOperationException.  But WPF will
>   be more efficient in its use of the object.

Taken From Here:

http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/freezable/